# Which terminal will KM Malta Airlines use at Heathrow?

Tags: lhr

Air Malta currently uses Terminal 4. Will KM Malta Airlines do the same?

Comment: The [KM Malta contacts webpage](https://www.kmmaltairlines.com/en/customer-support) offers several methods for asking questions of KM Malta. Have you asked them?